# iPhone Application - combination of UINavigationController and UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to make the login app with the complicated views.

Requirement flows as below:

```
Login Page --> Menu Page --> Detail Page with Tab Control. --> Navigation Page
```

Here the 'Detail Page' is again a combination of two views. Navigation View and Tab View.

i.e. 'Detail Page' will have a Navigation Control (Navigation Bar) on top and rest of the control is a Tab Control so that the user can switch between tabs at any point. If a user presses 'Next' from the navigation control, they will go to new page and can come back again to the 'Tab View' by pressing back from the next page.

Also I have lot more tabs which don't fit into a single tab view so I want the last tab to be like more option and will go to different views (either custom of table view).

Currently I have developed the Window base application as under.

1. Main Controller (MainSwitcherViewController) which is got initialized from the delegate.
2. This main controller has a reference of multiple other UIViewsController

   For example:

   - LoginViewController which is UIViewController.
   - MenuViewController which is UIViewController.
3. Initially I show the LoginViewController.
4. On successful login I show the MenuViewController.
5. And from the MenuViewController on any action (selection of Menu - currently added as UIButton), I am opening the NEW View but instead of New View (UIViewController) I want to go in Navigation View and Tab View combination View as explained above.

Here is my question:

1. Is my approach of designing the screen/views is correct or do I need to take another approach?
2. How to switch between UIViewController to TabViewController or NavigationViewController?
3. How to create combined Controller having Navigation Control on Top and on bottom TabBarViewControl such a way that for each tab Navigation Control is visible (shared).

I am a beginner at iPhone app development,

Please give me some pointers or links having similar kinds of examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first your approach is fine.  You can have a UITabBarController in the same class as a UINavigationController.  Just create the tab bar controller and in the same class also create the navigation controller.  The user will be able to use both from within that view.

To do this, in the class with the tab bar:

```
UITabBarController *mainTabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
```

Then add a the Views to that Tab Bar Controller.  In one of those UIViewController, add a navigation controller:

```
UIViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
mainViewController.title = @"Welcome";
UINavigationController *mainViewNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[mainViewNavController pushViewController:mainViewController animated:NO];
```

then just add the tab bar to the view along with the new views:

```
mainTabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray mainViewNavController, nil];
```

remember to only add the navigation controller to the tab bar controller becauase if you add the class as you normally would, it will not have the navigation controller features.

Hope this helps, if not, I'll be happy to clearify anything.